# Connect Trimble R10 GNSS to iOS and use external position

Tags: gps, trimble, ios, nmea

I want to pair a Trimble R10 to an iOS device and use the location data from the R10 in a iOS app.
I found [this tutorial](https://hf-files-oregon.s3.amazonaws.com/hdpkorecgroup_kb_attachments/2018/10-31/5dc9c7ae-5487-4c18-8486-f4fb1568bf7a/31.1-R10-NMEA-Output.pdf) and these [NMEA Bluetooth settings](https://support.prostarcorp.com/index.php?title=Trimble_R10_%26_SPS985_Integration_(Apple)), but I when I try to connect the iOS device with the R10 via Bluetooth, iOS states that the connection fails.

How does the R10 have to be configured in order to connect to the iOS device and can every iOS app use the location data from the R10 once it is connected?

Comment: check your device is compatible https://trl.trimble.com/docushare/dsweb/Get/Document-889531/TrimbleR10_Model-2_GNSSReceiver_UserGuide.pdf

Comment: This documents states "iPhone 6", so yes, it should be compatible...

Comment: What was Trimble's response to your support ticket about their hardware?

Comment: You say "I try to connect the iOS device with the R10 via Bluetooth, iOS states that the connection fails" - do you that mean on the Bluetooth Settings page, you see the R10 and tap on it and you don't connect?  Or is this in some application?  Once iOS is connected to the R10, iOS automatically uses positions from the R10.  There is no requirement to set up NMEA (the Bluetooth1 port would be used by Windows or Android, iOS uses a dedicated iAP port.)

Comment: @Trams Yes, I see  the R10 on the Bluetooth settings page and tap on it and it doesn't connect. Any idea what could cause this behaviour? On the R10 I/O settings page, I see 3 different Bluetooth entries (Bluetooth 1,2 and 3) and I can set them to NMEA and choose the NMEA sentences. Not sure wether some R10 I/O settings are wrong?

Comment: iOS does not use Bluetooth 1/2/3 ports when connecting to R10.  It uses a dedicated "iAP" port, which isn't shown in the R10 IO Configuration list and isn't configurable by user-level tools.  Changing BT 1, 2, 3 settings won't affect the iOS connection at all.  I'm not sure why the iOS BT connection would fail - I'll see if I can borrow an R10 and confirm that it works for me with iPhone 6.  The only thing I can suggest is to reset the receiver - under Receiver Configuration / Reset, select "Clear Satellite Data" - as far as I remember this clears GNSS data but also tidies up BT settings.

Comment: I can't find an R10, but I borrowed R2 and R12i and tried with those.  For each of those receivers, I opened Settings on my iPhone 6+ (Software Version 12.4.5), tapped Bluetooth, the receivers were listed under "Other devices", I tapped on them and they moved to "My Devices" section with Status "Connected".  So it just works for me!

Comment: The way I understand iOS behaviour, the moment a GNSS receiver is shown as connected, iOS may chose to use positions from the GNSS receiver but there's no guarantee iOS will use external GNSS position.  iOS moves in mysterious ways - it may choose to use locations based on WiFi networks instead.

Comment: Thank you @Trams, I will check with one of our R10.

Comment: With the R10, firmware version 5.50, it still fails to connect. Cannot update the firmware version at the moment. I will try with a R12i with the latest firmware next week.

Comment: Firmware might make a difference but FW 5.50 is quite recent, I'd expect it to work so I _guess_ that isn't the problem.  Have you only tried the one iPhone?  If the problem is with the Bluetooth pairing, you don't need any particular application on the phone so see if other phones have the same problem.

Comment: I tried different iPhones (6,8,11) with the R10, all fail - but R12i and iPhone worked flawlessly. Thanks for your hints!